# How to change text color in DatePicker Header Android

Tags: android, text, colors, header, datapicker

Hi I'am trying to change DatePicker Header text color, but I can't find attribute to change this. I want to change header color to white(I know how to do that) and Header text color to Black.

[image]

SOLUTION:

```
<style name="MyDatePickerStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:headerBackground">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

Comment: check my answer here on > **Change DatePicker header text color** http://stackoverflow.com/a/42460022/5188159

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xml

```
        <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/start_date_text"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:datePickerMode="spinner"
        android:calendarViewShown="false"
        style="@style/MyDatePicker" />
```

And style

```
<style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
     <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/Black</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I dont want to use spinner mode.

Comment: @remes try use `Widget.DatePicker` as parent

Comment: Thanks, You helped me a lot !