# How to change title color of DatePickerDialog?

Tags: android

**Update:**

Please read my question very carefully. I am trying to change the background colours of both title and header in the dialog. I am not trying to change any text color or only header background color.

**Question:**
I am using the material `DatePickerDialog` in my project. I am trying to change the title color which is in little dark color compared to the header background color. **I want the header background and title background to be same.**

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

I want to change the "Friday" title background color to the same normal green color of the header background. How can I achieve it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/8117793

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Datepicker dialog color for Android 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28738089/change-datepicker-dialog-color-for-android-5-0)

Comment: have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29014475/5110595)

Comment: Nope it didn't workout. still I can see the dark pink color behind "Friday" title. I want the header background and title background to be same. @SanjuBaghla

Comment: I want the header background and title background color to be same. @TominB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change DatePicker header text color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367430/change-datepicker-header-text-color)

Answer (score 0):

open colors.xml file and chane color as you want in these

```
<color name="colorPrimary">Your color</color>
 <color name="colorPrimaryDark">Your color</color>
 <color name="colorAccent">Your color</color>
```

Comment: Nope it didn't workout. still I can see the dark pink color behind "Friday" title. I want the header background and title background to be same.

Answer (score 0):

Add style like this and set to your `DatePicker`,

```
<style name="CustomDtPicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.Light.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/Green</item>
</style>
```

Note : You require minimum API level 21 to use this parent as you want Material DatePicker.